# Image deblurring using cepstrum analysis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to deblur an image I've blurred using gaussian filter, but using cepstrum analysis in MATLAB. So far I tried using "cceps" but there's a problem:

```
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in cceps>rcunwrap (line 149)
y(:) = y(:)' - pi*nd*(0:(n-1))/nh;

Error in cceps (line 80)
[ah,nd] = rcunwrap(angle(h));
```

My image is 512x512 double. I only saw array usage in cepstrum analysis. I'm trying to "cceps(y)-cceps(h)" (y: blurred image, h: gaussian filter) then "icceps" to get the deblurred (original) image.
Is there any way to use cceps and icceps for images? 
Also I tried applying the cceps algorithm;

```
Y=fftshift(fft2(y)); % Compute Fourier transform
CY=fftshift(ifft2(log(abs(Y)))); % Compute blurred image cepstrum
H=fftshift(fft2(h));
CH=fftshift(ifft2(log(abs(H)))); % Compute filter cepstrum
CX=CY-CH;
```

after this line I don't know how I can take the inverse cepstrum. There are some problems with unwrapping also, but I can't think of any way.